# Groovy Regex: String Split pattern not returning same result as Matcher pattern

Tags: regex, groovy, split

I'm trying to extract the data between a starting and ending markers in a string. There are multiple matches and I need to extract all the matches (into an array or list doesn't matter)

I have a limitation and cannot use Regex Matcher on my setup so as an alternative I'm looking at using `string.split()` with a regex.

```
def str = "USELESS STUFF START:M A:STUFF1 B:MORE2 C:THAT3 END:M START:M A:STUFF4 B:MORE5 C:THAT6 END:M START:M A:STUFF7 B:MORE8 C:THAT9 END:M USELESS STUFF"
```

This pattern works with Regex Matcher and extracts all the matches between the starting and ending marker.

```
def items = str =~ /(?s)(?<=START:M).*?(?=END:M)/
```

Result:

> [ A:STUFF1 B:MORE2 C:THAT3, A:STUFF4 B:MORE5 C:THAT6, A:STUFF7 B:MORE8 C:THAT9 ]

However, when I try to use the same pattern on `string.split`

```
def items = str.split(/(?s)(?<=START:M).*?(?=END:M)/)
```

it returns the end and start markers themselves for each match instead of what's between them.

> [USELESS STUFF START:M, END:M START:M, END:M START:M, END:M USELESS STUFF]

What am I missing, why isn't the Split pattern returning the same groups as Matcher pattern?

Comment: `split` cuts the string on each match, it doesn't return the matches. If you want the same result, use a pattern like `/START:M|END:M/` or `/.*?START:M|END:M.*?START:M|END:M.*/`

Comment: Perfect, the first one worked, the second one didn't work and only returned the last group and skipped the first two groups. Go ahead and answer the question and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior corresponds well to the method names:

- match `what text` ?
- split `by what separator` ?

What Groovy does in this case is essentially pour some syntactic sugar over the standard Java APIs. The line `def items = str =~ /(?s)(?<=START:M).*?(?=END:M)/`
is the same as

```
Matcher items = Pattern.compile("(?s)(?<=START:M).*?(?=END:M)").matcher(str);
```

The groups found by this matcher will be

```
 A:STUFF1 B:MORE2 C:THAT3 
 A:STUFF4 B:MORE5 C:THAT6 
 A:STUFF7 B:MORE8 C:THAT9
```

While the Matcher returns the matches, the Splitter, contrary, splits by them - it finds the parts of the text by the given regex and treats these as separators, cutting them out and returning what's left:

```
START:M
//  A:STUFF1 B:MORE2 C:THAT3 is cut out since it's a separator
END:M START:M
//  A:STUFF4 B:MORE5 C:THAT6 is a separator
END:M START:M
//  A:STUFF7 B:MORE8 C:THAT9 is a separator
END:M
```

To actually get the data between `START` and `END` marks, `str.split(" END:M START:M | START:M | END:M ")` would do. And the standard String methods like `indexOf`, `lastIndexOf` and `substring` can be very heplful to get rid of the useless stuff and get only the needed groups by simply removing all content before first `START:M` and after last `END:M`:

```
str.substring(str.indexOf("START:M ") + 8, str.lastIndexOf(" END:M"))
   .split(" END:M START:M ")

// or more groovy
str[str.indexOf("START:M ") + 8 .. str.lastIndexOf(" END:M") - 1]
   .split(" END:M START:M ")
```

(8 is the length of `START:M`)

Comment: Thanks, great inight but for me to accept the answer the key question was what pattern should i use in Split to replicate the Matcher behavior

Comment: What I didn't mention is was there was some "stuff" before the start and end separators so removing them would not be a good idea since I would end up adding that "stuff" to the first group. I'll update my question to indicate junk, so I guess the Split pattern would need to accomodate that, I'm okay with the stuff coming in as part of the groups, just separately

Comment: Great - please add that to the answer and I'll accept it